# How to Store value in database that automatically start with 1 and increment using annotation in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, annotations

I am storing values like **`names,password,username,email`** in database and i want that an **`id`** a **primary column** automatically created and it's **value start with 1 and automatically increment** . I am creating one  class `user` and it has data member like i write

```
    @Entity
     public class User extends Model {

    @Id(start)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Required
    @MinLength(value=4)
    public String username;
    @Required
    public String name;



    @Required
    @MinLength(value=6)
    public String password;

    @Required
    @Email
    public String email;

    public User(String name,String username,String password,String email)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        this.email=email;
    }


}
```

i am storing value in database and  it is storing value and creating id column in database like this screenshot of database

[image: database image]

In this screenshot it is creating random value and  storing that value in `id` column like `129 141 161 162` but i don't want this value i want that value will start with `1, 2,3` like this.

Please anyone have idea about which **annotation** i have to use for this that create column automatically and start value with 1? and **How to do it ?**

Give me some idea.

Comment: You can use @SequenceGenerator annotation. See more here [Java - JPA - Generators - @SequenceGenerator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator

Comment: ok it's fine but how to start value with 1?

Comment: You specify it on DB where you create the sequence. For example in oracle: CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
  MINVALUE value
  MAXVALUE value
  START WITH value
  INCREMENT BY value
  CACHE value;

Comment: I should point out that those numbers don't appear random, they appear to be sequential with gaps.  Oracle sequences can contain gaps.  Oracle does not guarantee consecutivity.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need consecutive values starting with 1 if you are using them as IDs?

Comment: I want to get particular value from database that's the reason i want to store data start with 1.

Answer (score 1):

dont know about create column automatically but here is how to fill it automatically:

first create sequence in database [SEQUENCE](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/sql-createsequence.html) than in entity class:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_increment")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_increment", sequenceName = "seq_name", allocationSize = 1)    
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

than when u add record to database column will be fill full with number from sequence +1

and ofc u will not need to set up id field earlier it will be set automatically

Answer (score 1):

The thing about GenerationType.AUTO is that the ID that it generates is unique at database level and is never recycled.  This means that in table1, your id field may increment from 2 to 6, if id's 3, 4 and 5 exist in other tables.

Try using the generation strategy GenerationType.IDENTITY (or GenerationType.SEQUENCE which has been explained in another answer).  The identity generation strategy manages unique id's per type hirarchy, so the id's are essentially sequential per table i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc....

Theres a great tutorial at [The ObjectDB Website](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated) for more information.