# Different column types for different databases with JPA

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa

Is there a posibility to define with JPA different column types depending on the used database?

I need to store the id as uuid and it must be protable. That's the problem. PostgreSQL has 'uuid', MSSQL 'uniqueidentifier' and Oracle has nothing, there must be used 'RAW', I think.

Have anybody an idea and can help me?

*Edit:* Currently the ids are generated with java.util.UUID and stored in the database as varchar. But because of performance problems with that data type I want to store the ids as a uuid type.
For Oracle must use the RAW type because no uuid type exist. How can I tell JPA use uuid type with PostgreSQ/MSSQL and RAW type with Oracle?

Comment: How is a varchar creating performance issues?  This is the first time I hear that.  I do not think the performance issue comes from the varchar but maybe from missing indexes and/or keys.

Comment: I don't think that the varchars are the cause of the performance problems. But using uuid types give 10% to 30% more performance.
And now my task is to find out how to use uuid type at all supported databases

Comment: Doing anything like that would need separation of metadata from classes, so 1 class can be used with different metadata depending on datastore (and you can't do that with annotations). JPA isn't flexible enough to provide that (even with its XML metadata); you may get some vendor specific option, but then lose vendor portability. The only persistence standard that allows all of that is JDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.UUID to generate your uuids and store it into a character varying(60) column type.
Now since you want to be a primary key it should be good to auto generate it a persist. So you can add on your class an entity listener at PrePersist:

```
@EntityListeners({ AbstractEntity.AbstractEntityListener.class})
public class Entity {

    public static class AbstractEntityListener {
        @PrePersist
        public void onPrePersist(Entity entity) {
            entity.uid();
        }
    }

    private String uid() {
        if (uid == null)
          uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return uid;
    }
}
```

Note that i didn't test this. So it may not work 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
I didn't explain it enough. That's the current state, the id is generated with java.util.UUID and stored in the database as varchar.
Now I want to store it as a uuid type, but Oracle doesn't have one.
This is my problem, how could I solve it?

I edit my question to make it more precise.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate as jpa provider, you could use something like this: @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")

Comment: I can do this, but then JPA creates crazy column types in the different databases. I want to specify what type is created for each database.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `SequenceGenerator`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator) for more details. You will have to make one seq. generator per entity in order to make sure you do not get concurrency problems.
Also make sure that you set a good/not existent initial value.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help me. I need UUIDs