# Multiple Column Types with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I need to specify multiple column types with JPA, because I support different databases in my application.

I googled but didn't found anything.

Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `multiple column types`?

Comment: Maybe different column types depending on the used database like me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460074/different-column-types-for-different-databases-with-jpa

Comment: JPA allows for overriding annotations in orm.xml files.  When you define the database in your persistence.xml, point it at a orm.xml that overrides the defaults with database specific types.  Other than that, handling database portability defaults will come down to provider specific code.

Comment: @JulianG: Thanks, this is almost the same question.

Comment: @Chris: I'm looking now for orm.xml. Thank you