# The duplicate key value JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have build a small application on SPring MVC + JPA + SQL Server. For some reasons I had to make some Entity changes in my application and I had to manually migrate some data from old Database to new Database(that have a bit different schema). After I migrated all the data I have such errors:

> 13:47:26.191 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__GLJourna__3213E83F741BD595'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.GLEntry'. The duplicate key value is (34903).

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class GLJournalEntry {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private BigDecimal amount;
private Date creationDate;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "glAccount_id", nullable = false)
private GLAccount glAccount;
private String notes;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ProductType productTyep;
private Date entryDate;
@Column(nullable = false)
private long transactionID;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EntryType type;
}
```

My guess is that I receive this error message because of default ID  annotation     @Id @GeneratedValue.

How can I fix it?  how can I generate ID in a way that it automatically got the latest ID from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to my problem was to change annotation to the Entity

Changed from :
`@Id @GeneratedValue`
to:
`@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequence functionality of the db to get unique ID, which will always be the new and latest one.

Use the link for more informations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator

Comment: how should I do that? I used this: '@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName="SEQUENCE_NAME", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="id_generator", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)' but same result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator , Refer the link hope it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your Database

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "ABC"."MY_SEQ" MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 2147483647 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 9130 CACHE 50 ORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get latest Id from DB by using custom logic. Sample what I did to resolve my issue. It works with Hibernate -

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="GeneratedId")
@GenericGenerator(name="GeneratedId",
                  strategy="....GenerateId"
)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

and

```
import org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator;
...
public class GenerateId extends IdentityGenerator {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenerateId.class.getName());

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
    String prefix = "M";
    Connection connection = session.connection();
    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = connection
                .prepareStatement("SELECT nextval ('seq_stock_code') as nextval");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("nextval");
            String code = prefix + StringUtils.leftPad("" + id,3, '0');
            log.debug("Generated Stock Code: " + code);
            return code;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e);
        throw new HibernateException(
                "Unable to generate Stock Code Sequence");
    }
    return null;
}
```