# JPA - Generated Id from Sequence is always 0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle9i

I'm trying to use JPA to generate IDs from sequences in my database (Oracle 9i)

From what I found here and there, here is the group of annotations I've set on my ID variable :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="PROCEDURENORMALE_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "PROCEDURENORMALE_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PROCEDURENORMALE_SEQ_GEN")
@Column(name = "IDPROCEDURENORMALE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
private long idProcedureNormale;
```

However, whenever I create a new object, this id is always set to 0, and because of that I can't persist data. I've tried to change the strategy from `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` to `GenerationType.AUTO`, nothing changed. For this specific table, Sequence number is supposed to be around 8300.

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: The ID is not generated when you create the object. It's generated when you persist it.

Comment: Check this out for sequencenumber generation [Java - JPA - Generators - @SequenceGenerator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator)

Comment: and what does the log say?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet for this information. The documentation I found on Oracle pages was unclear to me about this point.
I actually found the solution to my problem, which is posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my issue, that happened not to be directly related with what I exposed.

This object I was trying to persist is part of a relatively complex object, and in the parent object I didn't add a CascadeType to the JPA mapping annotation :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dossier")
private Set<Procedurenormale> proceduresNormales = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Changing this annotation to the following solved the issue :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dossier", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Procedurenormale> proceduresNormales = new HashSet<>(0);
```