# JPA SequenceGenerator: All generators in single table

Tags: java, jpa, sequence-generators

I'm using 3 different JPA SequenceGenerators. Everyone creates its own table in datasource with given name:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "a_seq", sequenceName = "A_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "b_seq", sequenceName = "B_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "c_seq", sequenceName = "C_SEQ")
```

Is there a way to combine them all in one table, let's say SEQUENCE table, and every generator is one row in this table?

Comment: Look at strategy "TABLE" which stores things in a table. SEQUENCE is for a native RDBMS SEQUENCE

Comment: Thanks, now i'm using tables. That's exactly what i was looking for. When you create an answer i will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Added an answer, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Table` generator (which stores the id value in a specified table) rather than `Sequence` generator (which uses native SQL sequences). This simplified example below should give you the idea, but you can control the schema for the table by specifying more attributes on the `@TableGenerator` annotation.

```
@TableGenerator(name="MyTableGen", table="SEQUENCES", pkColumnValue="MyClass")
@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="MyTableGen")
    private long myId;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this. sample code.

```
@Entity(name = "project_document")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idx;

    // ... setter, getter
}
```

...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
private long id;
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator)

Comment: AUTO means that the JPA provider will decide for itself which value generation strategy to use. So you could get AUTO_INCREMENT, or SEQUENCE or something else. Hence this does not answer the question.

Comment: oh. Neil.. see you again. okay i agree. my sample code is not good answer. but last link good answer.