# JPA entity sequence generating

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, sequence

In spring boot JPA I tried to implement sequence generator but it is not working.
the following is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_level")
public class RoleLevel implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "role_level_sequence", sequenceName = "role_level_id_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "role_level_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "role_level")
    private String roleLevel;

    @Column(name = "role_level_description")
    private String roleLevelDescription; 


   //getters and setters

}
```

when I insert value in directly through the database then next sequence from the db is not getting in jpa.it shows

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "role_level_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(7) already exists.
```

But the console shows

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('role_level_id_seq')
```

I think its not working.
Is there any solution for this.?

Comment: You can try this option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595124/java-jpa-generators-sequencegenerator

Comment: there is no verified answer in that question

Comment: try to generate the sequence"SELECT nextval('serial')" in the postgre console and check whether it is returning proper sequence and also check there is no manually added records. Everything is fine please remove strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE and try because you are asking schema generator to generate the sequence for you also you are trying to get the sequence too so anyone is fine.

Comment: Why do you have  `updatable = false`?

Comment: so problem when you insert postgres db side ? it works app side ?

Comment: @SpringerF   yes, works fine in app side